# Hyperleger Fabric and Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am very new to this Hyperledger thing. So I started with official courses present on their site. I tried to built small network using their samples. But i am very confused between Hyperledger composer and fabric. I have read that composer have some limitations, if you try to build network on composer and deploy on fabric. These composer are for developing POC, not for actual production. So please guide me through this what are the actual differences. Composer can be used for actual production or not, what are the limitations, where we can use composer and fabric, where we can use fabric sdk?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Fabric is the actual blockchain that runs the chaincode. Hyprledger Composer is a tool for writing, testing, and deploying chaincode to the Fabric.

If you're familiar with Ethereum, here's a rough analogy. You can use the geth console and compile your code manually using the solc compiler, or you can use Truffle, which simplifies a lot of tasks and adds a possibility to easily test and deploy the code.

Composer is a bit like Truffle in this analogy, but it is even more powerful. For example, it provides a possibility to declare your model, access control, and database queries. Sometimes that's enough for a BNA, and you don't even have to write any executable code. Plus, you have a lot of command-line functionality for just about everything.

And yes, it's perfectly suitable for actual production. It's just that newer Fabric versions might have new features that are not supported by Composer, so you might have to wait until they are.